# Any way to access array element with variable concatenation

Tags: php

Is there anyway to access array "$a" given a variable with a string path through array "$a"?

For example:

```
$b = "['one']['1.1']";
$a = array(
    'one' => array(
        '1.1' => 'One point One',
        '1.2' => 'One point Two',
    ),
    'two' => array(
        '2.1' => 'Two point One',
        '2.2' => array(
            '2.2.1' => 'Two point Two point One',
        ),
    ),
);

echo ${$a.$b};
```

I have attempted ${$a.$b} and several other variations, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: I needed to use it in an application but found another / better way. However I was still curious. It was something like unset($a.$b);
Ended up just using &$var as reference and doing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) for this purpose. However, please be wary that there is probably a better way to do what your doing and anything put into `eval()` should be well sanitized.

```
eval("echo \$a$b;");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the eval() option as pointed out,  and personally I am not an eval hater in the right circumstances.

I just wanted to suggest that perhaps there is a better way of dealing with your issue though.

Now I don't understand where the variable $b is coming from, but it would seem to be much more usable for you if you stored it as 2 variables, and then you could use them directly to access the array, such as:

```
  $b = 'one';
  $c = '1.1';
$a = array(
    'one' => array(
        '1.1' => 'One point One',
        '1.2' => 'One point Two',
    ),
    'two' => array(
        '2.1' => 'Two point One',
        '2.2' => array(
            '2.2.1' => 'Two point Two point One',
        ),
    ),
);

echo $a[$b][$c];
```

If you have no control over the variable $b,  or you are using it to describe an array of variable depth, you could simplify it's structure into something like 'one-1.1'  or 'one-two-1.1' and parse the variable into the indexes that you require.

For example :

```
    $b = 'one-1.1';

$a = array(
    'one' => array(
        '1.1' => 'One point One',
        '1.2' => 'One point Two',
    ),
    'two' => array(
        '2.1' => 'Two point One',
        '2.2' => array(
            '2.2.1' => 'Two point Two point One',
        ),
    ),
);

function resolveArray($path, $array)
{    
    $indexes = explode('-', $path);
    $depth = count($indexes);

    $target = $array;

    for($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++)
    {
        $target = $target[$indexes[$i]];
    }

     return $target;   
}

echo resolveArray($b, $a);
```

You could modify the above to deal with your path as described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no built-in shortcut like you want. You could try to use `eval()` but I really does not recommend it